# typescript how to declare nested data type from interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript interface:

```
interface IFoodShop {
    name: string;
    owner: string;
    foods: Array<{
        id: number,
        name: string,
        isVegetarian: boolean
    }>
}
```

I have a function that requires the paramater to be the same data type as the foods array from interface IFoodShop. How would i declare it, similar to something this, which doesn't work.

```
// check if food is vegetarian
isVegatarianFood(data: IFoodShop.foods) {


}
```

I understand I can break down the data types like below:

```
interface IFoodShopFood {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    isVegetarian: boolean
}

interface IFoodShop {
    name: string;
    owner: string;
    openDate: Date;
    foods: IFoodShopFood
}

// check if food is vegetarian
isVegatarianFood(data: IFoodShopFood) {


}
```

But this to me seems unecessary when I have a lot of arrays to declare. How would I simply say that the data type needs to match the nested interface data type foods?

Comment: I think in the second example it should be `foods: IFoodShopFood[]`, otherwise it's not an array anymore. What do you mean by unnecessary? If you want to use types in multiple places you have to define it. You could a also define a new type that is the same structural-wise, but that would be a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 11):

> But this to me seems unecessary when I have a lot of arrays to declare.

You can use the following syntax (its called a *lookup type*):

```
interface IFoodShop {
    name: string;
    owner: string;
    foods: Array<{
        id: number,
        name: string,
        isVegetarian: boolean
    }>
}
// check if food is vegetarian
function isVegatarianFood(data: IFoodShop['foods']) { }

isVegatarianFood([{ id: 123, name: '123', isVegetarian: true }]); // okay
isVegatarianFood([{ id: 123, name: '123', isVegetarian: 'ERRROR' }]); // ERROR
```

Comment: Nice. – Nightly version is no longer needed. Plus you can also use this syntax in the interface: `foods: { /* ... */ }[];`

Comment: @martias cheers. Updated. Also added name for the concept for searchability 